# React native : mix blend mode possible?

Tags: react-native

is it possible to use `mix-blend-mode` in `RN`?

```js
    style={{
      mixBlendMode: 'overlay'
    }}
```

Got invalid props.style key

Comment: Any followup on this? I tried the repos @TuckerConnelly posted without much success.

Comment: Any update on this??

Answer (score 4):

If you need to blend images you can try my [react-native-image-filter-kit](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) this way:

```js
    import { Image } from 'react-native'
    import { OverlayBlend } from 'react-native-image-filter-kit'

    const imageStyle = { width: 320, height: 320 }
    
    const tahoe = (
      <Image
        style={imageStyle}
        source={{ uri: 'https://una.im/CSSgram/img/tahoe.jpg' }}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      />
    )

    const cacti = (
      <Image
        style={imageStyle}
        source={{ uri: 'https://una.im/CSSgram/img/cacti.jpg' }}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      />
    )

    const blended = (
      <OverlayBlend
        dstImage={tahoe}
        srcImage={cacti}
      />
    )
```

[image: result]

Comment: i want to achieve this kind of dripping effect. 
https://www.pinterest.cl/pin/579768152020249192. 
Can you help me in this regards ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.

Closest you could get would be https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react-native with https://github.com/CAPSLOCKUSER/gl-react-color-blending